# Compile Error while intializing a List from Custom Setting

Tags: apex, customsetting

From Manual

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm

Custom Setting Examples

The following example uses a list custom setting called Games. 
Games has a field called GameType.
This example determines if the value of the first data set is equal to the string PC.*

```
List<Games__C> mcs = Games__c.getall().values();
boolean textField = null;
if (mcs[0].GameType__c == 'PC') {
  textField = true;
}
system.assertEquals(textField, true);
```

---

As shown above from the manual, a list gets intialized with custom settings data.

When I try to do a similar thing I am getting the following error.

Can someone tell me why ?

```
List<AllowedCombinations__c> sb = AllowedCombinations__c.getAll().values;
```

> Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: MAP at line 24 column 82

Comment: You are missing the "()" that signifies that values is a method not a field.

Comment: How silly of me ..tx

Comment: Maybe one to delete?

Comment: Keith you should post that as an answer, someone could easily hit the same thing and be searching for that error message.